# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Blog with 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error whenever I delete a certain blog post. It does sound logical because it's searching for `@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])` and since the deleted one lost it's ID it'll most likely throw that error. But in my blog controller I did write a redirect option so that when the post gets deleted the user goes back to the main blog path but it is not working.

Destroy method:

```
  def destroy
    if @blog.destroy
      redirect_to blog_path
    end
  end
```

I also tried adding an if statement to check whether the param is in the database or else do a redirect instead:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @question = Question.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
    if @blog 

    else
      redirect_to blog_path
    end
  end
```

But none seemed to work. Here's the blog controller:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @question = Question.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
    if @blog 

    else
      redirect_to blog_path
    end
  end

  def new
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
    if user_signed_in?
      @blog = current_user.blogs.build
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  def edit
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def create
    @blog = current_user.blogs.build(blog_params)
    @blog.save
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def update
    @blog.update(blog_params)
    respond_with(@blog)
  end

  def destroy
    if @blog.destroy
      redirect_to blog_path
    end
  end

  private
    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    end

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :content, :avatar)
    end
end
```

The show view:

```
<div class="signin">
    <div class="container">
    <h3 class="media-heading red noHoverRed"><%= @blog.title %></h3>
    <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="well">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <br/>
                      <p><%= @blog.content.html_safe %></p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="pull-right">
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <% if @blog.user.username == current_user.username %>
                            <%= link_to 'edit', edit_blog_path(@blog), :class => "text-muted links" %>
                            <%= link_to "", blog_path(@blog), :class => "fa fa-close text-muted links", :method => :delete %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>           
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Auther -->

              <div class="well">
                  <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left">
                    <% if @blog.user.avatar.blank? %>
                        <img src="http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png" style="width: 75px;">
                    <% elsif @blog.user.avatar %>
                        <%= image_tag @blog.user.avatar, :style => "width:75px;" %>
                    <% end %>
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <p>About <%= link_to @blog.user.username, @blog.user, :class => " bg" %></p>
                   </div>
                    <% if @blog.user.about.blank? %>
                        <p class="text-left">Apparently, this user prefers to keep their information a mystery.</p>
                    <% else %>
                        <p><%= @blog.user.about.html_safe %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>

        <!-- Comments -->

              <div class="well">
                <%= render :partial => @blog.comments %>
              </div>
              <br/>

              <div class="well">
                <%= form_for [@blog, Comment.new], :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
                    <%= f.text_area :body %>
                    <%= f.submit %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                <br>
                    <p><span style="padding-right: 10px;" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> posted <%= time_ago_in_words(@blog.created_at) %> ago </span></p>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="well">
                    <h4 class="red">Recent Questions</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <% @questions[0,7].each do |question| %>
                        <p><%= link_to question.title, question %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="well">
                    <h4 class="red">Sponsors</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <img src="http://webneel.com/daily/sites/default/files/images/daily/03-2013/4-animal-rights-sweden-boxer-animal-ad.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Blog model:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers
  end

  resources :blogs do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments

  resources :answers

  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'
  resources :users

end
```

And my server log:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=4):
  app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:57:in `set_blog'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
 (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues
/layout (50.0ms)
```

Comment: What is the output of `Blog.find(4)` in your `rails console`?

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=4`

Comment: Well, according to code, you are destroying the whole blog (not the blog post),  and then you redirect to it.

Comment: Since there is no such record ,try this `if` clause.
`if @blog.nil?
   redirect_to root_path
end`

Comment: @BroiSatse Yeah basically I am destroying the entire `blogs/:id` from the database and trying to redirect to `/blogs/` instead

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 it did not work

Comment: @Raymond - In that case change `blog_path` to `blogs_path` in your redirection. ;) url_helpers in controller has an "extra feature" to include current params when building an url, which is why it manages to do the redirection. However it redirects you to wrong page. :) Your show action in given form will give incorrect redirection error.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was with [sureshprasanna70](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3552298/sureshprasanna70)'s comment and by changing the redirect_to. When I added the if statement that sureshprasanna70 suggested, it stopped displaying the error but chrome started to crash because the loop was redirecting to the show method itself.

The fix:

From:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @question = Question.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
    if @blog 

    else
      redirect_to blog_path
    end
  end
```

To:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    @question = Question.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("created_at desc")
    if @blog.nil?
      redirect_to blogs_path
    end
  end
```